# How to add multiple values to a claim in policy

Tags: azure-api-management

I am working with API Management policy expressions and trying to create a claim with multiple values dynamically. I have a list of string values and want to create a claim values from that string list.
e.g  "123232,43434,545455,5656565,676767" and i want to add these values to claim dynamically

```
<validate-jwt............>
<required-claims>   
<claim name="test" match="any">
  <value> </value> how can i create multiple value dynamically 
</claim>
</required-claims>
</validate-jwt>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can split the string to array and apply claims like below:

```
<required-claims>
        <claim name="group" match="any">
            <value>value[0]</value>
            <value>value[1]</value>
        </claim>
 </required-claims>
```

Also refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#authorize-access-to-operations-based-on-token-claims

Comment: Yes but number of values in string are not fixed and it can change.

Comment: ok, I am not quite sure though..but you could try looping through the array with  

{% for x in values %}
   {
      <value>{{values[x]}}</value>
   }
   {% endfor %}

Comment: I already tested in this way and  Policy give  error  "The element 'claim' cannot contain text. List of possible elements expected: 'value'."